# polymer init bash: polymer: command not found

Tags: angular, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, ui-design

Install git.
Install the latest version of Bower.
npm install -g bower
npm install -g polymer-cli
install these one 
but
 polymer init
bash: polymer: command not found
i am trying so many times but not resolve this error please solve this error
$ npm install -g polymer-cli
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o                                                                                                                n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible                                                                                                                . Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade                                                                                                                 to lodash@^4.0.0.
C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\                                                                                                                node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "polymer-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\                                                                                                                Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\no                                                                                                                de_modules.polymer-cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\a                                                                                                                ction\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\instal                                                                                                                l\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\                                                                                                                Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\no                                                                                                                de_modules.polymer-cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData                                                                                                                \Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\n                                                                                                                ode_modules.polymer-cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\a                                                                                                                ction\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\instal                                                                                                                l\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\                                                                                                                Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Haresh\AppData\Roaming\npm\no                                                                                                                de_modules.polymer-cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Haresh\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Answer (score 0):

type ...

```
which polymer (linux)
```

at the command line to find where polymer is installed (if anywhere).

```
where polymer (windows)
```

if the location where it is installed is not in your PATH then it wont find it. You will need to add the folder where the executable is located to the path for it to work.

Comment: Polymer (Windows)

Comment: What about polymer in mac